# Storing shapes as objects into array list

Tags: java, user-interface, drawing

My main goal is to have a user draw a shape and then store that shape into an arraylist so that when the user activates the actionlistener to draw another shape, the others shapes won't disappear.

Code is pretty basic, but as you can see. I have a for - loop with another class called Rect. Rect has a constructor taking in the coordinates that drew the users rectangle. I want to take in the coordinates, store them as an object into some arbitrary arraylist rectList and then have them redraw using a for-loop so they stay on the screen. I am confused because I have an arraylist RectList in my main class (containing my Draw class), but I need to get the rectangle object that is built in the Rect class into my rectList arraylist.

My user currently draws a rectangle:

```
 private class Draw extends JPanel
  {

     public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
      {
       super.paintComponent(page);


       //draw all rectangles
          for (int i=0; i < rectList.size(); i++)
            {
              ((Rect) rectList.get(i)).draw(page);
            }


          if (mouseDragged == true) 
           {
            page.drawRect(x1, y1, x3-x1, y3-y1);
            page.fillRect(x1, y1, x3-x1, y3-y1);

           }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by figuring how to store the object into the array.

rectList.add(new Rect(1st coordinate, 2nd coordinate, end coordinate 1, end coordinate 2, rectangleColor));